# TypeScript nested asynchron functions

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

`profile.page.ts:`

```
  username: string;
  totalScore: number;
  ...


  loadUserData() {
    this.spinnerDialog.show();
    this.firebaseServie.loadUserData().then(() => {
      this.username = this.sessionData.getUser().getUsername();
      this.totalScore = this.sessionData.getUser().getTotalScore();
       ....
    });
```

`firebase.service.ts`:

```
async loadUserData() {
    console.log(this.sessionData.getUser().getEmail());
    this.userCollection = this.afs.collection('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', this.sessionData.getUser().getEmail().toLowerCase()));

    this.userDoc = this.afs.collection("users").doc(this.sessionData.getUser().getEmail().toLowerCase());

    this.x = this.userDoc.valueChanges().subscribe(((item: User) => {
      this.userLoadedUser = item;
      console.log("Found user by email id " + this.sessionData.getUser().getEmail() + ":" + this.userLoadedUser.username);
      this.sessionData.getUser().setUsername(this.userLoadedUser.username);
      this.sessionData.getUser().setTotalScore(this.userLoadedUser.totalScore);
      ....

    }));
  }
```

So how can I be sure that the part in the `then()` clause is only executed after we have the data from firebase?

I have edited my question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return a new Promise in your `firebase.service.ts`:

```
loadUserData() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        ...
        this.x = this.userDoc.valueChanges().subscribe(((item: User) => {
            ...
            resolve(); // If everything worked!
        }));
        ...
    });
}
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since subscribe indicates you're dealing with an observable, better don't start mixing with a promise, but simply use the observable and `pipe`

```
otherfunc()
    .pipe(map(myfunc))
    .subscribe((item:User) => {

});
```

If you really want the promise, you can convert the observable to a promise.

```
otherfunc().toPromise().then(myfunc).then(e => {
    // runs after
});
```

Comment: what if the above function is on a page component and the below one is in a service?

Comment: Simple call the Service method then. Doesn’t really matter where it is as long as it’s accessible

Comment: Yes, but `.pipe(map(myfunc))` requires me to import the page-module into the service, which is not a good programming style. See on my `profile.page.ts` (angular) I have `this.firebaseServie.loadUserData().then(() => { // here html field values are set` and then I have my `firebase.service.ts`: `async loadUserData() { .... this.x = this.userDoc.valueChanges().pipe().subscribe(((item: User) => { // here I load the data from firebase` so only once the firebase data is loaded, the values of the html fields should be set. thats what i want

Comment: i have edited my question for a better understanding